# Saving FIRServerValue.timestamp() - Hashable protocol error

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The following code successfully saves data ("test":FIRServerValue.timestamp()) to my Firebase database:

```
let updateData = [ "[agent]:\(self.messageText)": (FIRServerValue.timestamp()) ] as [String : Any]

    let update = self.dbConnector.child("messages/\(key)")
    update.updateChildValues(updateData) { (error, dbRef) in
        if (error == nil) {
            // ok
        } else {
            // failed
        }
    }
```

However, I want the timestamp to be the key and the "test" to be the value, eg. FIRServerValue.timestamp():"test"

When I switch them around to this:

```
let updateData = [(FIRServerValue.timestamp()) : "test"] as [Any : String]
```

I get the error:

```
Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
```

Having read a few other questions around Hashable protocols I am confused whether this is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FIRServerValue.timestamp()** is a command that is send to your Firebase Server, which then creates an timeStamp value and then stores it.

If you print you get a null dictionary, How a dictionary works is that your key value pair of dictionary cannot have a null key, Since you dont recieve a key of **FIRServerValue.timestamp()** in your front end, its still null in the updateValues.

So you cannot define an empty key

Comment: Thanks. I've altered my approach and fetched the saved timestamp from a previous method and then used it that way.